# jqGrid filter searches but pagination is lost after search when attempting to navigate within the pagination

Tags: jqgrid

I've implemented a button on the navgrid toolbar to perform a custom filter search.  When the search is completed, the correct number of results is displayed and the pagination index changes.  When any button to move within the pagination is used, the filters are lost and the grid reverts to the unfiltered results.  The function to perform the filtered search is:

```
function jqGridFilter(filtersparam, grid, reload) {
 grid.setGridParam({
    postData: {
        filters: filtersparam
    },
    search: true
 }); 
 if(reload == 1){ 
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
 }   
};  

var filters = { "groupOp": "OR", "rules": [{ "field": "y2012qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2012qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2012qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2012qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2013qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2013qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2013qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2013qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2014qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2014qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2014qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2014qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2015qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2015qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2015qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2015qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2016qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2016qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2016qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2016qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2017qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2017qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2017qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2017qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" }] };
```

And the call to this function is:

```
$grid.navButtonAdd(pagerName,
  {
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-star",
    title:'Filter Rows Where Quarter Values Are All 0',
    onClickButton : function () {
    jqGridFilter(null , $(this),0);
    jqGridFilter(filters , $(this),1);
    jqGridFilter(null , $(this),0);
  }
});
```

The grid is populated by a remote JSON object and is set to loadonce: true.  The toolbar search is also enabled and the pagination does not revert when using the toolbar search.

Any ideas on how to hold the filtered pagination with the filtering in place until a reloadgrid trigger or refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last call to the jqGridFilter function was clearing the filter parameters, once I removed the last call, the paging worked with only the filtered data.